# Asynchronous Execution of UPDATEs without wait

Tags: poco-libraries

There is a code in DataUserManual about Asynchronous Execution:

```
Statement stmt = (ses << "SELECT (age) FROM Person", into(age), async); // asynchronous statement
Statement::Result result = stmt.execute(); // executes asynchronously
stmt.execute(); // throws InvalidAccessException
```

It's about that we should always call wait on result before execute a next request.

What about a case when I don't expect any answer on requests from DB? Is is safe to asynchronously call a chain of UPDATEs without waiting for result?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the exception is because the statement is still executing. If you want to issue updates in parallel, you need separate Statement objects.

Comment: So if I just create a new Statement for every new UPDATE it will be ok?

Comment: You can create as many statements as you want but whether it will be ok from your environment, I/O and DB resources, I can not answer.